# another function runs before end of jquery ajax request in contempt of the app order

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, ecmascript-6

I'd like in the first function to get response from api and put it into the object field and then in the second function log it. 
App starts, when we call init function - **initApp()**, which describes the same order: first get data, then log it.

```
class App {
    constructor() {
        this.data;
    }

    // init app
    initApp() {
        this.getServerData();
        this.foo();           
    }

    // get data using ajax
    getServerData() {
        $.ajax({
                url: 'https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com' + '/posts/1',
                method: 'GET',
                dataType: 'json',
            })
            .then(data => {
              //  putting data to object field
                this.data = data;
            })
            .catch(error => {
                console.log(error);
            });
    }

    // log it
    foo() {
        console.log('another function in action, api response:');
        console.log(this.data);
    }
}

const app = new App();
app.initApp();
```

But the field `app.data` is undefined, cause `foo()` runs before `getData()` ends.
It's probably to solve adding `setTimeot()` to `initApp()`

```
// init app
initApp() {
    this.getData();
    setTimeout(() => {
            this.foo();
        },
        1000
    );
}
```

Is it normal or it would be better to use other cases?

Problem is that in my real app besides one `foo()` will be another 5-7 functions. And put all of them into `.then` ? 
Maybe there are other solutions?

Any help will be highly appreciated.

Comment: Wouldn't calling `foo` from `.then` be simpler?

Comment: simplest approach is using callback. Please check my answer below. Let me know if any problem u r facing or want to optimize anything else.

Comment: Edited description. In case of 1 foo() of course, but if there will be 5-10 ?

Comment: `this` would be `jqxhr` at `.then()` within `getServerData`?

Comment: @guest271314  no, `this` is still instance of App,  at `.then()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use callback here.

```
// init app

var self=this;
initApp() {
    this.getServerData(function(){ self.foo();  });

}

// get data using ajax
getServerData(callback) {
    $.ajax({
            url: 'https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com' + '/posts/1',
            method: 'GET',
            dataType: 'json',
        })
        .then(data => {
          //  putting data to object field
            this.data = data;
            callback()  ;          
        })
        .catch(error => {
            console.log(error);
        });
}
```

Comment: But what's the best case if we will add 
foo2()
foo3()
foo4()
?
In this case all application logic wiil be included in `.then`, right ?

Comment: No. it will be added inside initApp(). Check i have called self.foo() there. So it can be self.foo();self,foo2() etc ...

Answer (score 0):

call foo() from response of ajax call, this will make sure that foo will be executed only after ajax call.